# How can I send button toggles in an HTML form to a google script for processing?

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script

I have a bunch of buttons in a form that are toggle-able. Upon submitting the form, I want the script on the server side to be able to know which buttons were clicked. I know I can do this with checkboxes but I want to know if there's a way to do something similar using buttons instead.

Comment: You can use the DOM to check the state of the button when the form is submitted.  There is a way to do what you want.  But you really need to post the HTML for a button, and any JavaScript and CSS that goes with it.

Comment: If you are using a custom html web form, you could try using [App Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/overview). You could follow this tutorial about [showing how to save data to a google doc spreadsheet from any html form](https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-form-send-email-via-google-script-without-server/). This would help you understand how HTML and Apps Script can interact and pass data.

Comment: You can also check the [Execution API](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/rest/api), this consists of a single scripts resource, which has a single method, run, that makes calls to specific Apps Script functions. Hope this helps.